# Creating map series in tif format with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, tiles

I would like to tile a rendered ArcMap 10.6 project in tif format(2km x 2km). The map is simply a colour topographic map rendered in black and white. Important is that the resultant images use the colormap configured in arcmap and not the raw data.

Which tools can do this or would this need to be scripted?

Comment: By "map series" do you mean just consistently designed, related maps, or do you want to build a map book (one map, multiple pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["Data driven pages"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-data-driven-pages.htm) do exactly that. (but the output is PDF file if you need tif you will need to convert after the export...)

You just need to create an index layer (in your case a grid representing the tile you want), create a layout you want and set the data driven page.

When exporting your map, choose PDF as export format (that's the only one where you get the pages tab in the export option) and choose the right option for you.

Comment: Choose the separate pages option when exporting a data driven map, rather than one file. There is a PDF to GeoTIFF geoprocessing tool, but it sounds like you just need TIFs, which can be created from PDFs in Adobe.